# Function to return the same output for any input in Scala

Tags: scala, function

Suppose I have a function type `Foo` like this:

```
type Foo = (Int, Int, Int) => String
```

Now I would like to define a variable of type `Foo` to always return `"abc"` for any arguments

```
val foo: Foo = (_, _, _) => "abc"
```

Can it be simplified ?

Comment: Outside of this question, what are you trying to do? Returning `abc` for any given input sounds odd.

Comment: This is an artificial example. I am making a mock for tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really a simplification in length (is a character longer) but a simplification in the way that you don't need to write as many place holders as long you parameter list is:

```
val foo: Foo = { case _ => "abc" }
```

Comment: Thanks. I meant the number of placeholders.

Comment: @Michael With this approach you might have `type Foo2 = (Int, Int) => String` and still use the same function definition: `val foo: Foo2 = { case _ => "abc" }`

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Not sure if I use your solution but it looks like real simplification. Especially if I have a function of five arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> def f[A](x: A*): String = "Foo"
f: [A](x: A*)String

scala> f( 1, 2, 3)
res3: String = Foo

scala> f( List(1), 5)
res4: String = Foo
```